# Cannot find symbol Java error?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, symbols

The code works when I used `java.util.Arrays.sort(numbers);`
Am I doing something wrong? This seems weird to me.

```
import java.util.Arrays.*;

class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] numbers = {6.0, 4.4, 1.9, 2.9, 3.4, 3.5};
    char[] chars = {'a', 'A', '4', 'F', 'D', 'P'};

    sort(numbers);

    System.out.println(binarySearch(numbers, 3));

   }
}
```

(Error displayed in terminal)

```
Test.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
    sort(numbers);
    ^
symbol:   method sort(double[])
location: class Test
 Test.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println(binarySearch(numbers, 3));
                       ^
 symbol:   method binarySearch(double[],int)
 location: class Test
  2 errors
```

Comment: How do you imagine Java can find the method if you remove the class name ?

Comment: what do you mean remove the class name? you mean `Arrays.sort`?

Comment: You changed "Arrays.sort" to "Arrays". "Arrays" is the class name.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's a static method of the class *Arrays*.

You should invoke it like this:

```
Arrays.sort(someArray);
```

Note you still have to import the Arrays class like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Or as others have mentioned, if you do a static import you can omit the class name.

I would argue that `Arrays.sort()` is better for readability.

Comment: I tried to run with the `Arrays.sort(numbers)`, it didn't work. It works If I just use `sort(numbers)` and important with `import static`

Comment: to use Arrays.sort you need to use import java.util.Arrays;

Answer (score 6):

you need to do a static import. Use the following

`import static java.util.Arrays.*;`

**Reason**

when you want to import some static members (methods or variables), you need to static import the members. So you have to use `import static`

**Another solution**

or you can import

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

and use

```
Arrays.sort(b);
```

**Reason of the second Solution**

here you are not importing any static elements so normal import to Arrays is needed. Then you can directly access using `Arrays.sort`

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to do a *static import*, but you missed `static`.

```
//   add v this
import static java.util.Arrays.*;
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, but why are some people saying use `Arrays.sort(array)`, this also gives me an error even though I imported with static

Comment: They are giving an alternative: Do a normal import: `import java.util.Arrays;` _and_ you can say `Arrays.sort(someArray);`.